# How would I go about writing a script in AppleScript to send multiple pings to pre-determined URLs?

Tags: applescript

Complete AppleScript noobie here. How would I go about writing and executing a script that sends (let's say) 3 pings to a series of URLs ?

Instead of manually sending 3 pings to address 1, address 2, etc... ?

There would be approximately 100 addresses to send pings too.

Answer (score 0):

I use to Here is an example with only 1 URL address. you can loop via a repeat/end repeat to run it through all your address list.

```
Set myAddress to "myserveur.local"
Set Feedback to do shell script "ping -c3 " & myAdress
```

Feedback variable will contains result of the ping. I suggest you to include in your ping command a grep to extract OK of not.